# clustering of a fasta file having DNA sequences to find the most unmatched clone

Tags: python, data-science, cluster-analysis, biopython

I am trying to make a cluster to analyze DNA sequences and find the less matched patterns among them (for say <25% match).
Is it possible to perform cluster analysis (k-means or any other approach) for the DNA in a fasta file.

for example I want to generate a cluster graph (image) for the given data (below is the fasta sequences) and find the less similar (<25%) sequence (encircled dots)

```
>1
 GATGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCCTT
 >2
 CAGTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTTGTTC
 >3
 CGGTATTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTATGCTCGAAAGGAATTTCTATTGAAAGGTATTGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCCTTTCTAT
 >4
 CGGTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTC
 >5
 GATGTACTTCGTTCCAGTTGTGTGTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTTCAACGTGAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCAACTTTGAATTTG
 >6
 CAATGTACTTCGTTCGGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCC
 >7
 CAAACACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCC
```

[image]

Comment: Also see this related question: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15813/how-do-i-plot-clusters-based-on-dna-sequence-alignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function to convert DNA sequence to one-hot encoding
def one_hot_encode(sequence):
    mapping = {'A': [1, 0, 0, 0], 'C': [0, 1, 0, 0], 'G': [0, 0, 1, 0], 'T': [0, 0, 0, 1]}
    return [mapping[base] for base in sequence]

# DNA sequences in fasta format
sequences = {
    ">1": "GATGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCCTT",
    ">2": "CAGTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTTGTTC",
    ">3": "CGGTATTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTATGCTCGAAAGGAATTTCTATTGAAAGGTATTGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCCTTTCTAT",
    ">4": "CGGTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTC",
    ">5": "GATGTACTTCGTTCCAGTTGTGTGTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTTCAACGTGAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCAACTTTGAATTTG",
    ">6": "CAATGTACTTCGTTCGGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCC",
    ">7": "CAAACACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCC"
}

# Assign different colors to sequences
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple', 'brown', 'pink']

# One-hot encode sequences
sequences_matrix = np.array([np.concatenate(one_hot_encode(seq)) for seq in sequences.values()])

# Perform PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_result = pca.fit_transform(sequences_matrix)

# Plot PCA results with different colors
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
for i, seq_key in enumerate(sequences.keys()):
    plt.scatter(pca_result[i, 0], pca_result[i, 1], color=colors[i], label=seq_key)

plt.title('PCA of DNA Sequences')
plt.xlabel('Principal Component 1')
plt.ylabel('Principal Component 2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

u can also cluster as dendrogram

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function to calculate Hamming distance between two DNA sequences
def hamming_distance(seq1, seq2):
    return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(seq1, seq2))

# DNA sequences in fasta format
sequences = {
    ">1": "GATGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCCTT",
    ">2": "CAGTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTTGTTC",
    ">3": "CGGTATTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTATGCTCGAAAGGAATTTCTATTGAAAGGTATTGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCCTTTCTAT",
    ">4": "CGGTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTC",
    ">5": "GATGTACTTCGTTCCAGTTGTGTGTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTTCAACGTGAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCAACTTTGAATTTG",
    ">6": "CAATGTACTTCGTTCGGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCC",
    ">7": "CAAACACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCC"
}

# Create a matrix of pairwise Hamming distances
num_sequences = len(sequences)
distance_matrix = np.zeros((num_sequences, num_sequences))

for i, seq1_key in enumerate(sequences.keys()):
    for j, seq2_key in enumerate(sequences.keys()):
        seq1 = sequences[seq1_key]
        seq2 = sequences[seq2_key]
        distance_matrix[i, j] = hamming_distance(seq1, seq2)

# Perform hierarchical clustering
linkage_matrix = linkage(distance_matrix, method='complete')

# Plot the dendrogram
labels = list(sequences.keys())
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
dendrogram(linkage_matrix, labels=labels, orientation='right')
plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram')
plt.xlabel('Hamming Distance')
plt.show()
```

[image]

try this

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

# Example DNA sequences in a FASTA file
example_fasta = ">1\nGATGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCCTT\n" \
                ">2\nCAGTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTTGTTC\n" \
                ">3\nCGGTATTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTATGCTCGAAAGGAATTTCTATTGAAAGGTATTGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCCTTTCTAT\n" \
                ">4\nCGGTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTC\n" \
                ">5\nGATGTACTTCGTTCCAGTTGTGTGTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTTCAACGTGAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCAACTTTGAATTTG\n" \
                ">6\nCAATGTACTTCGTTCGGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCC\n" \
                ">7\nCAAACACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCC"

# Save example data to a FASTA file
fasta_file = "example_fasta.fasta"
with open(fasta_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(example_fasta)

# Read DNA sequences from the FASTA file
sequences = list(SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"))
dna_sequences = [str(seq.seq).upper() for seq in sequences]

# Define a function to convert DNA sequences to numerical representation
def dna_to_num(seq):
    return np.array([ord(base) for base in seq])

# Convert DNA sequences to numerical data
dna_data = np.array([dna_to_num(seq) for seq in dna_sequences])

# Apply PCA for dimensionality reduction
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_data = pca.fit_transform(dna_data)

unique_labels = set(kmeans.labels_)
print(f"Number of clusters: {len(unique_labels)}")

# Apply KMeans clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(pca_data)

# Plot the clustered data
# Plot the clustered data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

# Dynamically generate colors based on the number of clusters
colors = cycle(['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm'])

for i, label in enumerate(set(kmeans.labels_)):
    cluster_points = np.array([pca_data[j] for j, l in enumerate(kmeans.labels_) if l == label])
    plt.scatter(cluster_points[:, 0], cluster_points[:, 1], color=next(colors), label=f'Cluster {label}')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
# Plot the clustered data with sequence annotations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

# Dynamically generate colors based on the number of clusters
colors = cycle(['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm'])

for i, label in enumerate(set(kmeans.labels_)):
    cluster_points = np.array([pca_data[j] for j, l in enumerate(kmeans.labels_) if l == label])
    plt.scatter(cluster_points[:, 0], cluster_points[:, 1], color=next(colors), label=f'Cluster {label}')

    # Annotate points with sequence identifiers
    for j, seq_label in enumerate(sequences):
        if kmeans.labels_[j] == label:
            plt.annotate(seq_label.id, (pca_data[j, 0], pca_data[j, 1]), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(5,5), ha='right')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

U can also label based on threshold

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example DNA sequences in a FASTA file
example_fasta = ">1\nGATGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCCTT\n" \
                ">2\nCAGTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTTGTTC\n" \
                ">3\nCGGTATTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTATGCTCGAAAGGAATTTCTATTGAAAGGTATTGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCCTTTCTAT\n" \
                ">4\nCGGTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTC\n" \
                ">5\nGATGTACTTCGTTCCAGTTGTGTGTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTTCAACGTGAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCAACTTTGAATTTG\n" \
                ">6\nCAATGTACTTCGTTCGGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCC\n" \
                ">7\nCAAACACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGCTCAAGGAGATTTTCAACGTGAAAAAAATTATTATTCGCAATTCCTTTAGTTGTTCC"

# Save example data to a FASTA file
fasta_file = "example_fasta.fasta"
with open(fasta_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(example_fasta)

# Read DNA sequences from the FASTA file
sequences = list(SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"))
dna_sequences = [str(seq.seq).upper() for seq in sequences]

# Map DNA bases to numerical values
base_mapping = {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'G': 2, 'T': 3} #I shifted here befor def dna_to_num, use any one def, and avoid repetation

def dna_to_num(seq):
    return np.array([base_mapping.get(base, -1) for base in seq if base in base_mapping])

dna_data = np.array([dna_to_num(seq) for seq in dna_sequences])




def dna_to_num(seq):
    return np.array([base_mapping[base] for base in seq])

dna_data = np.array([dna_to_num(seq) for seq in dna_sequences])

# Perform PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_data = pca.fit_transform(dna_data)

# Perform KMeans clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(pca_data)

# ... (previous code)

# Set the threshold for labeling
labeling_threshold = 0.75


colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm']
for i, label in enumerate(set(kmeans.labels_)):
    cluster_points = np.array([pca_data[j] for j, l in enumerate(kmeans.labels_) if l == label])
    plt.scatter(cluster_points[:, 0], cluster_points[:, 1], color=colors[i], label=f'Cluster {label}')

    # Annotate points with sequence identifiers if similarity is below the threshold
    for j, seq_label in enumerate(sequences):
        if kmeans.labels_[j] == label:
            similarity_to_centroid = np.linalg.norm(pca_data[j] - kmeans.cluster_centers_[label])
            if similarity_to_centroid < labeling_threshold:
                plt.annotate(seq_label.id, (pca_data[j, 0], pca_data[j, 1]), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(5,5), ha='right')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

or if u want to display only certain based on threshold

```
    # Map DNA bases to numerical values
base_mapping = {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'G': 2, 'T': 3}

# Read DNA sequences from the FASTA file
sequences = list(SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"))
dna_sequences = [str(seq.seq).upper() for seq in sequences]

def dna_to_num(seq):
    return np.array([base_mapping.get(base, -1) for base in seq])

dna_data = np.array([dna_to_num(seq) for seq in dna_sequences])

# Perform PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_data = pca.fit_transform(dna_data)

# Perform KMeans clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(pca_data)

# Set the threshold for labeling
labeling_threshold = 0.75

colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm']
for i, label in enumerate(set(kmeans.labels_)):
    # Annotate points with sequence identifiers if similarity is below the threshold
    for j, seq_label in enumerate(sequences):
        if kmeans.labels_[j] == label:
            similarity_to_centroid = np.linalg.norm(pca_data[j] - kmeans.cluster_centers_[label])
            if similarity_to_centroid < labeling_threshold:
                # Show point only for points below the threshold
                plt.scatter(pca_data[j, 0], pca_data[j, 1], color=colors[i])
                plt.annotate(seq_label.id, (pca_data[j, 0], pca_data[j, 1]), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(5,5), ha='right')

plt.axis('equal')  # Make sure the plot is in equal scale
plt.show()
```

[image]

if u want to encircle threshold

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# ... (previous code)

# Set the threshold for labeling
labeling_threshold = 0.75

colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm']

for i, label in enumerate(set(kmeans.labels_)):
    cluster_points = np.array([pca_data[j] for j, l in enumerate(kmeans.labels_) if l == label])

    # Annotate points with sequence identifiers if similarity is below the threshold
    in_threshold_points = []
    for j, seq_label in enumerate(sequences):
        if kmeans.labels_[j] == label:
            similarity_to_centroid = np.linalg.norm(pca_data[j] - kmeans.cluster_centers_[label])
            if similarity_to_centroid < labeling_threshold:
                in_threshold_points.append((pca_data[j, 0], pca_data[j, 1]))
                plt.annotate(seq_label.id, (pca_data[j, 0], pca_data[j, 1]), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(5, 5), ha='right')

    # Draw circles around the points within the threshold
    if len(in_threshold_points) > 0:
        for point in in_threshold_points:
            circle = plt.Circle((point[0], point[1]), labeling_threshold, color='black', fill=False)
            plt.gca().add_patch(circle)

    plt.scatter(cluster_points[:, 0], cluster_points[:, 1], color=colors[i], label=f'Cluster {label}')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. I have a question. what if we have thousands of clone sequences, how we will assign the colors? Is there no way to assign colors based on the similarity as shown in the example picture attached with my question ie  what if I want to create only 3 or 5 clusters?

Comment: I edited, just check

Comment: Ya, sure, u can even select cluster based on threshold, aswell u can chose how many cluster do u want, in updated code I have given n_cluster = 5, this u can adjust, I did some work to select the cluster based on threshold

Comment: 1.  function (def dna_to_num(seq) is defined twice.
2. Can you please give a little bit explanation for the function (def dna_to_num(seq)) i.e what it does or returns in terms of value or array. and also shows base_mapping not defined error.

Comment: it showing not defined because in def dna_to_num we used "base_maping " words, right so we have to define first so, befor def dba_to_num, we should write or keep base_mapping = {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'G': 2, 'T': 3}, this, one, since it got duplicate, u can remove any one def, but make sure keep base_mapping before def,

Comment: also The dna_to_num(seq) function essentially maps DNA bases to numerical values according to the base_mapping dictionary provided. It takes a DNA sequence (seq) as input and returns an array of corresponding numerical values. For instance, if the input sequence is "ATCG", the function will return an array [0, 3, 2, 1], where 'A' is mapped to 0, 'T' to 3, 'C' to 1, and 'G' to 2 based on the base_mapping dictionary.

Comment: Thanks. with protein sequences base_mapping = {'A': 0,'C': 1,'D': 2,'E': 3,'F': 4,'G': 5,'H': 6,'I': 7,'K': 8,'L': 9,'M': 10,'N': 11,'P': 12,'Q': 13,'R': 14,'S': 15,...}
it throws the below error. 
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  dna_data = np.array([dna_to_num(seq) for seq in dna_sequences])
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Also do I need to perform multiple sequence alignment (MSA) before clustering if DNA/Protein clones are not of same length?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have to look into it, that may be different approach, like u can see within aligned sequence, but again u have to trim for that,  Many ways are there, it's a basic I showed here, it depends how u take forward

Comment: Can u post your sequence, or can u post new query

Comment: Please find my sequences as below 
>127
AVTLGESGGGLQTPGGALSLVCKGSGFTLSSFNMGWVRQAPGKGLEWVGVISSSGRYTEYGAAVKGRAAISRDDGQSTVRLQLNNLRAEDTAIYFCAKGIGTAYCGSCVGEIDTWGHGT
>144
AVTLDESGGGLQTPGGGLSLVCKASGFTFSSHGMGWVRQAPGKGLEFVADISGSGSSTNYGPAVKGRATISRDNGQSTVRLQLNDLRAEDTATYYCAKYVGSIGCGSTAGIDAWGHGT
>291
AVTLDESGGGLQTPGGALSLVCKASGFTFSDRGMHWVRQAPGKGLEWVAGIGNSGSGTTYGSAVKGRATISRDNGQSTLRLQLNNLRPEDTATYFCARATCIGSGYCGWGTYRIDAWGHGT
>381
AVTLDESGGGLQTPGGALSLVCKASGFTFSRFNMFWVRQAPGKGLEWVAAISSGSSTWYGSAVKGRATISRDNGQSTVRLQLNNLRAEDTGTYYCTKAAGNGYRGWTTYIAGWIDAWGHGT

Comment: >3971
AVTLDESGGGLQTPGGALSLVCKASGFTFSDRGMGWVRQAPGKGLEFVACIENDGSWTAYGSAVKGRATISRDNGQSTVRLQLNNLRAEDTATYYCAKSAGGSLLLTVVILTVGSIDAWGHGT
>3186
AVTLGESGGGLQTPGGALSLVCKASGFTFSSHGMAWVRQAPGKGLEFVAGIGNTGSNPNYGAAVKGRATISRDNRQSTVRLQLNNLRAEDTGTYFCAKRAYAASWSGSDRIDAWGHGT
>3066
AVTLGESGGGLQTPGGGLSLVCKASGFTFSSFNMFWVRQAPGKGLEYVAGIDNTGSYTAYGAAVKGRATISRDNGQSTLRLQLNNLRAEDTATYYCAKSFDGRYYHSIDGVDAIDAWGHGT
>3719
AVTLGESGGGLQTPGGTVSLVCKGSGFDFSSYNMQWVRQAPGKGLEFIAQINGAGSGTNYGPAVKGRATISRDNGQSTVRLQLNNLRAEDTAIYYCAKSYDGRYYHSIDGVDAIDAWGHGT

Comment: Hi, can u post it as a new query

Comment: Hi Umar, I have created a new query. Please have a look.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77960057/clustering-for-the-protein-sequences-with-without-msa

Comment: Please see my responce,if any aditional u need I will correct it